# Как применить feBlend и сохранить source alpha

Tags: svg, filter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь изменить цвета изображения, применив к ним `feFlood` и `feBlend`  в режимах `lighten` и `darken`.

Как сохранить при этом альфа-канал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg>
  <filter id="filter">
    <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="blue" />
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="flood" mode="lighten" />
  </filter>
  <image filter="url(#filter)" href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/utqghr0o/

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50445913/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Способ работы `lighten` заключается в том, что он принимает максимальное значение цвета от каждого канала, каждого из двух входов (предварительно умноженное на альфа).

Поэтому, если пиксель имеет нулевую непрозрачность, он никогда не будет считаться максимальным цветом для любого канала, и будет использоваться значение с другого входа.

То, что вам нужно сделать, - это сначала наполнить поток альфой из исходного изображения (`Source Alpha`), а затем смешать `masked flood`  поток с исходным изображением.

### #1 Вариант `mode="lighten"`

```html
<svg width="544" height="184">
  <filter id="filter">
    <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="blue" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="lighten" />
  </filter>
  <image filter="url(#filter)" width="544" height="184" href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</svg>
```

### #2 Вариант `mode="darken"`

```html
<svg width="544" height="184">
  <filter id="filter">
    <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="blue" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="darken" />
  </filter>
  <image filter="url(#filter)" width="544" height="184" href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</svg>
```

### #3 Вариант `mode="normal"`

```html
<svg width="544" height="184">
  <filter id="filter">
    <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="blue" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="normal" />
  </filter>
  <image filter="url(#filter)" width="544" height="184" href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</svg>
```