# Как сверстать блок с линиями отходящими от центральной картинки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобными блоками?

[image: скриншот блока, который нужно сверстать]

Не представляю, как это можно реализовать. Вряд ли получится с помощью абсолютного позиционирования адаптивно сверстать такое.

UPD1: Сложность заключается в верстке линий, отходящих от центральной картинки, в верстке блоков текста ничего сложного для меня нет.

Comment: А зачем их верстать? Оставьте картинкой

Comment: Может быть svg?

Comment: Как сказали товарищи выше, обычно, в таких случаях, используют svg/картинки. В ином случае без JavaScript вам не обойтись. Не могу представить себе, как этот блок будет выглядеть на телефонах.

Comment: @AshenOne а ведь как-то делают. Много раз такое видел и всегда удивлялся.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров когда с коллегой разрабатывали сайт, он тоже столкнулся с похожей проблемой - нужна была адаптивная карта ветки метро - линия, а к ней ведут линии от остановок. В итоге он взял svg, изменял ориентацию на горизонтальную на телефонах, заказчик сказал "супер". Лично я не могу представить, как этот блок будет выглядить на узких экранах телефона - точно уж не в таком виде, как есть. Если заказчик не указал что нужно именно так, можно смело вставлять картинкой и не заморачиватся, иначе много времени уйдёт в никому не нужный функционал.

Comment: А адаптивно - это как именно? Просто размеры меняются или углы наклона тоже?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Вариант с применением двух изображений

При этом решение используется `pattern` для добавления второго круглого изображения в центре.

**Решение адаптивно, вёрстка не сломается при изменении размера окна браузера и при просмотре на любом гаджете.**

- Фоновое изображение добавляется с помощью команды:

```
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4A4.jpg" y="-70" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="0.45" />
```

Затемняется командой - `opacity="0.45"`
Позиционируется координатами - `x` и `y`
Изображение полностью заполняет родительский блок `<div class="container">` и может быть вставлено, как самостоятельный элемент в любое место веб страницы.

- Круглое изображение добавляется поверх фонового изображения с помощью
  `<pattern>`

```
 <pattern id="ptn1"
          x="-60"   
          width="220"
          height="250"
           patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <image width="220" 
         height="220" 
          preserveAspectRatio="none"
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD9UI.jpg"/>
 </pattern>
```

***Ниже полный код приложения:***

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke-width:2;
    stroke:#45228B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 962 732" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <defs>
 
   <pattern id="ptn1"
           x="-60"   
           width="220"
           height="250"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="220" 
          height="220" 
           preserveAspectRatio="none"
          xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD9UI.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
 <!-- Фоновое изображение -->
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4A4.jpg" y="-70" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="0.5" />
   <!-- Центральный круг и линии выноски --> 
  <circle cx="488" cy="359.2" r="120"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#45228B"/>
  <path d="m591.3 297.2 96.5-67.4h162.3M386.5 296.7l-93.2-67.4" class="s0" />
  <path d="m386.5 296.7-93.2-67.4h-186.4 1.1" class="s0" />
  <path d="m589.3 420.6 95.4 67.4h164.5" class="s0" />
  <path d="m387.2 425.2-95.4 67.4h-188.6" class="s0" />
  <path d="m541.5 251.6 143.7-202.9-202.9 2.2" class="s0" />
  <path d="m426.9 461.8-131.6 206.2c0 0 432.4-5 289.7-1.1" class="s0" /> 
   
   <!-- Круглое изображение в центре-->
   
  <circle  stroke-width="3" fill="url(#ptn1)" stroke="white"  cx="488" cy="359.2" r="110" /> 
  
  
  <g fill="#45228B" font-weight="600">
   <text x="489" y="42" font-size="20" > Быстрый старт </text> 
    <text x="700" y="200" font-size="20" > Низкая стоимость  </text> 
     <text x="700" y="220" font-size="20" >  входа в бизнес </text> 
      <text x="360" y="600" font-size="20" > Система обучения </text> 
     <text x="360" y="625" font-size="20" > вашего персонала и </text> 
    <text x="360" y="650" font-size="20" > помощь в его подборе </text> 
   <text x="160" y="160" font-size="20" > Простая, </text> 
  <text x="160" y="185" font-size="20" > проверенная </text> 
   <text x="160" y="215" font-size="20" > бизнес модель </text>  
     <text x="690" y="478" font-size="20" > Бизнес - любимое дело </text>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Вариант с применением фильтров

Если выбранное изображение устраивает вас по содержанию, но в связи с требованиями дизайна нужно сменить цвет оттенка фона или цвет фигур, то совсем не обязательно дорабатывать картинку в фотошопе, можно её перекрасить с помощью комбинации фильтров: `feflood`, `feComposite`, `feBlend`
Техника применения этих фильтров подробно объясняется [в топике на нашем сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/832128/28748)

**#1 Вариант с покраской фигур**

В фильтре `<feblend>` применяется оператор `mode="lighten"`

`<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="lighten" />`

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke-width:2;
    stroke:#D57700;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 962 732" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <defs>
   <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
     <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#9F46CB" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="lighten" />
  </filter>
    </filter> 
   <pattern id="ptn1"
           x="-60"   
           width="220"
           height="250"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="220" 
          height="220" 
           preserveAspectRatio="none"
          xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD9UI.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
 <!-- Фоновое изображение -->
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4A4.jpg" y="-70" width="100%" height="100%"  filter="url(#solid)" />
   <!-- Центральный круг и линии выноски --> 
  <circle cx="488" cy="359.2" r="120"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#D57700"/>
  <path d="m591.3 297.2 96.5-67.4h162.3M386.5 296.7l-93.2-67.4" class="s0" />
  <path d="m386.5 296.7-93.2-67.4h-186.4 1.1" class="s0" />
  <path d="m589.3 420.6 95.4 67.4h164.5" class="s0" />
  <path d="m387.2 425.2-95.4 67.4h-188.6" class="s0" />
  <path d="m541.5 251.6 143.7-202.9-202.9 2.2" class="s0" />
  <path d="m426.9 461.8-131.6 206.2c0 0 432.4-5 289.7-1.1" class="s0" /> 
   
   <!-- Круглое изображение в центре-->
   
  <circle  stroke-width="3" fill="url(#ptn1)" stroke="white"  cx="488" cy="359.2" r="110" /> 
  
  
  <g fill="#D57700" font-weight="600">
   <text x="489" y="42" font-size="20" > Быстрый старт </text> 
    <text x="700" y="200" font-size="20" > Низкая стоимость  </text> 
     <text x="700" y="220" font-size="20" >  входа в бизнес </text> 
      <text x="360" y="600" font-size="20" > Система обучения </text> 
     <text x="360" y="625" font-size="20" > вашего персонала и </text> 
    <text x="360" y="650" font-size="20" > помощь в его подборе </text> 
   <text x="160" y="160" font-size="20" > Простая, </text> 
  <text x="160" y="185" font-size="20" > проверенная </text> 
   <text x="160" y="215" font-size="20" > бизнес модель </text>  
     <text x="690" y="478" font-size="20" > Бизнес - любимое дело </text>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

**#2 Вариант с покраской фона**

В фильтре `<feblend>` применяется оператор `mode="darken"`

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke-width:2;
    stroke:#E1E1E1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 962 732" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <defs>
   <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
     <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#9F46CB" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="darken" />
  </filter>
    </filter> 
   <pattern id="ptn1"
           x="-60"   
           width="220"
           height="250"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="220" 
          height="220" 
           preserveAspectRatio="none"
          xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD9UI.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
 <!-- Фоновое изображение -->
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4A4.jpg" y="-7" width="100%" height="100%"  filter="url(#solid)" />
   <!-- Центральный круг и линии выноски --> 
  <circle cx="488" cy="359.2" r="120"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#E1E1E1"/>
  <path d="m591.3 297.2 96.5-67.4h162.3M386.5 296.7l-93.2-67.4" class="s0" />
  <path d="m386.5 296.7-93.2-67.4h-186.4 1.1" class="s0" />
  <path d="m589.3 420.6 95.4 67.4h164.5" class="s0" />
  <path d="m387.2 425.2-95.4 67.4h-188.6" class="s0" />
  <path d="m541.5 251.6 143.7-202.9-202.9 2.2" class="s0" />
  <path d="m426.9 461.8-131.6 206.2c0 0 432.4-5 289.7-1.1" class="s0" /> 
   
   <!-- Круглое изображение в центре-->
   
  <circle  stroke-width="3" fill="url(#ptn1)"   cx="488" cy="359.2" r="110" /> 
  
  
  <g fill="#E1E1E1" font-weight="600">
   <text x="489" y="42" font-size="20" > Быстрый старт </text> 
    <text x="700" y="200" font-size="20" > Низкая стоимость  </text> 
     <text x="700" y="220" font-size="20" >  входа в бизнес </text> 
      <text x="360" y="600" font-size="20" > Система обучения </text> 
     <text x="360" y="625" font-size="20" > вашего персонала и </text> 
    <text x="360" y="650" font-size="20" > помощь в его подборе </text> 
   <text x="160" y="160" font-size="20" > Простая, </text> 
  <text x="160" y="185" font-size="20" > проверенная </text> 
   <text x="160" y="215" font-size="20" > бизнес модель </text>  
     <text x="690" y="478" font-size="20" > Бизнес - любимое дело </text>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

> Надеюсь работники офисов не будут на меня в обиде за беззлобную
>   шутку-картинку, демонстрирующую их тяжкий повседневный труд. Это скорее сочувствие.
>   Может быть вы улыбнетесь, глядя на эту картинку и вам станет легче переносить самодура-начальника  в повседневности.

Чтобы получить адаптивное приложение, которое будет работать во всех современных браузерах, необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

- Загружаем выбранную картинку в векторный редактор и устанавливаем
  размеры svg полотна равные ширине и высоте растрового изображения

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="962" height="732" viewBox="0 0 962 732" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdPiI.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

- В векторном редакторе с помощью инструмента - `Рисовать кривые Безье`
  добавляем нужные контуры линий для размещения поясняющего текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в формате SVG и прогоняем его через [оптимизатор](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)
  для получения чистого кода без лишнего кода от `Inkscape`
- Чтобы получить центральную, круглую часть изображения более светлую
  по сравнению с остальным фоном изображения, применяем комбинированную
  маску, где центральный круг имеет атрибут `fill="white"`, что делает
  его полностью прозрачным.

  `rect` имеет более темную закраску `fill="#978300"`, поэтому   фон будет затемненным.

`<mask id="msk1">
   <rect fill="#978300" width="100%" height="100%"/>
     <circle fill="white" cx="488" cy="359.2" r="110" /> 
  </mask>`

- Добавляем текст

Ниже полный код:

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke-width:2;
 stroke:#45228B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 962 732" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
   <rect fill="#BBA200" width="100%" height="100%"/>
     <circle fill="white" stroke-width="3" stroke="red"  cx="488" cy="359.2" r="110" /> 
  </mask>
</defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPxW2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
  <circle cx="488" cy="359.2" r="120"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#45228B"/>
  <path d="m591.3 297.2 96.5-67.4h162.3M386.5 296.7l-93.2-67.4" class="s0" />
  <path d="m386.5 296.7-93.2-67.4h-186.4 1.1" class="s0" />
  <path d="m589.3 420.6 95.4 67.4h164.5" class="s0" />
  <path d="m387.2 425.2-95.4 67.4h-188.6" class="s0" />
  <path d="m541.5 251.6 143.7-202.9-202.9 2.2" class="s0" />
  <path d="m426.9 461.8-131.6 206.2c0 0 432.4-5 289.7-1.1" class="s0" />
  
  <g fill="#45228B">
   <text x="493" y="42" font-size="20" > Быстрый старт </text> 
    <text x="700" y="200" font-size="20" > Низкая стоимость  </text> 
     <text x="700" y="220" font-size="20" >  входа в бизнес </text> 
      <text x="360" y="600" font-size="20" > Система обучения </text> 
     <text x="360" y="625" font-size="20" > вашего персонала и </text> 
    <text x="360" y="650" font-size="20" > помощь в его подборе </text> 
   <text x="120" y="160" font-size="20" > Простая, </text> 
  <text x="120" y="185" font-size="20" > проверенная </text> 
   <text x="120" y="215" font-size="20" > бизнес модель </text> 
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Та же техника реализации с другой картинкой:

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke-width:2;
 stroke:#45228B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 962 732" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
   <rect fill="#BBA200" width="100%" height="100%"/>
     <circle fill="white" stroke-width="3" stroke="red"  cx="488" cy="359.2" r="110" /> 
  </mask>
</defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRfB4.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
  <circle cx="488" cy="359.2" r="120"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#45228B"/>
  <path d="m591.3 297.2 96.5-67.4h162.3M386.5 296.7l-93.2-67.4" class="s0" />
  <path d="m386.5 296.7-93.2-67.4h-186.4 1.1" class="s0" />
  <path d="m589.3 420.6 95.4 67.4h164.5" class="s0" />
  <path d="m387.2 425.2-95.4 67.4h-188.6" class="s0" />
  <path d="m541.5 251.6 143.7-202.9-202.9 2.2" class="s0" />
  <path d="m426.9 461.8-131.6 206.2c0 0 432.4-5 289.7-1.1" class="s0" />
  
  <g fill="#45228B">
   <text x="493" y="42" font-size="20" > Быстрый старт </text> 
    <text x="700" y="200" font-size="20" > Низкая стоимость  </text> 
     <text x="700" y="220" font-size="20" >  входа в бизнес </text> 
      <text x="360" y="600" font-size="20" > Система обучения </text> 
     <text x="360" y="625" font-size="20" > вашего персонала и </text> 
    <text x="360" y="650" font-size="20" > помощь в его подборе </text> 
   <text x="120" y="160" font-size="20" > Простая, </text> 
  <text x="120" y="185" font-size="20" > проверенная </text> 
   <text x="120" y="215" font-size="20" > бизнес модель </text> 
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @ЯсыревМихаил Да не за что. Рад был помочь

Answer (score 8):

Вот SVG вариант.

Я умышленно ставлю вьюбокс наполовину в отрицательную область (`viewbox="-100 -100 200 200"`), чтобы координата `0,0` была в центре картинки, так легче из головы брать точки для полилиний без дополнительной арифметики.

```html
<svg viewbox="-100 -100 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" height="1" width="1">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q67w.gif"
             height="70px" width="70px" ></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q67w.gif" opacity="0.3" 
         x="-100" y="-100" height="200" width="200" transform="scale(-1,1)"></image>
  
  <g stroke="black" fill="none">
    <polyline points=" 20  90 -40  90 0 0"></polyline>
    <polyline points="-20 -90  40 -90 0 0"></polyline>
    <polyline points="-90 -50 -50 -50 0 0"></polyline>
    <polyline points="-90  50 -50  50 0 0"></polyline>
    <polyline points=" 90  50  50  50 0 0"></polyline>
    <polyline points=" 90 -50  50 -50 0 0"></polyline>
  </g>  

  <circle r="35" stroke="black" fill="url(#image)"></circle>
  
  <text x="-20" y="88">hello</text>
  <text y="-78">    
    <tspan x="-20" >row 1</tspan>
    <tspan x="-20" dy="20px">row 2</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с помощью псевдоэлемента и CSS. Вместо `after` можно использовать SVG элемент.

```css
.title {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.title::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  bottom: -69px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotate(25deg);
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="title">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на CSS (смотреть на весь экран).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}


.section::before,
.section::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section::before {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/a0ZySrQ.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(200%);
}

.section::after {
  background: rgba(92,0,155,.65);
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/a0ZySrQ.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

.circle .item {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle .item .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle .item .title::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle .item:nth-child(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 200px);
  left: 50%;
}

.circle .item:nth-child(1) .title::after {
  width: 133px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% + 250px);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(2) .title::after {
  width: 96px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(3) {
  top: calc(50% + 100px);
  left: calc(50% + 250px);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(3) .title::after {
  width: 84px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: rotate(-150deg);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(4) {
  width: 200px;
  top: calc(50% + 200px);
  left: 50%;
}

.circle .item:nth-child(4) .title {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.circle .item:nth-child(4) .title::after {
  width: 149px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: rotate(-65deg);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(5) {
  top: calc(50% + 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(5) .title::after {
  width: 86px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: rotate(145deg);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(6) {
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
}

.circle .item:nth-child(6) .title::after {
  width: 104px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: rotate(-145deg);
}


.circle .item .msg {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Быстрый старт</div>
      <div class="msg">При четком следовании инструкциям вы откроете центр через 1,5 месяца.</div>
    </div>
      <!---->
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Низкая стоимость входа в бизнес</div>
      <div class="msg">Для открытия одного центра вам понадобиться всего от 870 000 руб (включая все расходы)</div>
    </div>
      <!---->
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Бизнес - любимое дело</div>
      <div class="msg">Это бизнес станет любимым как только вы увидите эмоции ваших маленьких клиентов и их родителей</div>
    </div>
      <!---->
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Система обучения вашего персонала и помощь в его подборе</div>
      <div class="msg"></div>
    </div>
      <!---->
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Маркетинговая поддержка</div>
      <div class="msg">Все макеты рекламных материалов, размещение на федеральном сайте, в соц. сетях и четкие рекомендации по поиску клиентов.</div>
    </div>
      <!---->
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Простая проверенная бизнес-модель</div>
      <div class="msg">Мы даём вам четкий алгоритм по открытию центра и стратегию продвижению, которые проверены в реальной жизни.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ (+)